# Passing entity of core data model as function parameter, error

Tags: swift, core-data

I have Model named: *Year*, In this model I have entity named: Spring, Summer, Autumn and Winter.

The function is:

```
    func saveToDisk<T: NSManagedObject>(of entityName: T.Type, with context: NSManagedObjectContext, and dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>)
        {
         let season= entityName.init(context: context)
        

                  if let iconName = dictionary["iconName"] as? String
                    {
                       season.iconName = iconName
                    }
}
```

**In above code I receive error: value of type 'T' has no member 'iconName'**

Code to call function:

```
for jsonDictionary in jsonArray
     {
                        
     switch monthCount
         {
            case 1…2:
                    saveToDisk(of: Winter, with: coreDataStack.managedContext, and:  jsonDictionary)
            case 3…5:
                    saveToDisk(of: Spring, with: coreDataStack.managedContext, and: jsonDictionary)
            case 6…8:
                    saveToDisk(of: Summer, with: coreDataStack.managedContext, and: jsonDictionary)
            ....

         }
      }
```

Here's the class derived from Editor> CreateNSManaged Subclass from Model entity.

```
@objc(Winter)
public class Winter: NSManagedObject { }         

extension Winter {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Winter> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Winter>(entityName: “Winter”)
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: Date?
    @NSManaged public var iconName: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type `T` in `saveToDisk` doesn't provide the properties of the `NSManagedObject` subclass at compile time which is necessary to access `iconName`.

There are two solutions:

1. Use KVC (Key-Value Coding)

   ```
   if let iconName = dictionary["iconName"] as? String {
       season.setValue(iconName, forKey: "iconName")
   }
   ```
2. Create a protocol

   ```
   protocol Season {
       var iconName: String? {get set}
   }

   class Winter: NSManagedObject, Season {}
   ```

   and

   ```
   func saveToDisk<T: NSManagedObject>(of entityName: T.Type, 
                                        with context: NSManagedObjectContext, 
                                      and dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>) where T : Season
   ```

Comment: Thank you Vadian, This worked like a charm.

You  rock \m/.